# Unable to create environment in conda using yml file

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to create an environment using yml file and conda. However the create env fails.

The YML file :

```
name: respro
channels:
- defaults
dependencies:
- jupyter
- matplotlib=2.0.2
- numpy=1.13.1
- pandas=0.20.3
- python=3.5.4
- scikit-learn=0.19.0
- scipy==1.1.0
- seaborn=0.9.0
- pip:
 - tensorflow==1.15.0
 - tensorboard==1.15.0
```

create command

`conda env create -f respro.yml`

Console :

```
$ conda env create -f respro.yml
Warning: you have pip-installed dependencies in your environment file, but you do not list pip itself as one of your conda dependencies.  Conda may not use the correct pip to install your packages, and they may end up in the wrong place.  Please add an explicit pip dependency.  I'm adding one for you, but still nagging you.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::ipykernel-4.10.0-py35_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::ipykernel-4.10.0-py35_0
location of failed script: C:\Users\Username\.conda\envs\respro\Scripts\.ipykernel-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:
stderr:
return code: 1

()
```

Please help in resolving this. Tried searching for why it fails, however not getting clarity on the cause.

Comment: is there a specific reason that you fix all versions? Try relaxing some constraints, maybe another version of tthat package is installable

Comment: Earlier I had used the same yml file but without the seaborn dependency and it had worked. However recently it does not work even if I remove seaborn dependency. How can I identify which are the right versions to use? The console failure messages arent giving much clarity on which version to use.

Comment: Can you try the same command, but set `-v -v` (yes, twice) and add that output to the question?

Comment: I was able to finally resolve by moving jupyter from dependencies to pip, not sure why this resolved but it worked. Thank you all for your inputs

Comment: That is not really a great fix (as it does not really fix but circumvent the problem). I suspect that you have a corrupt file in your `pkgs` folder. Try deleting the files in there

Comment: Not sure, but since the Python is old, it might be needed to add the **free** channel below the **defaults** entry. Also, newish packages may be incompatible with this old Python, but the old packages may not have appropriate upper bounds on the version constraints. All that said, you might need to constrain to the `ipykernel` package to being older.